# Virtual pad for linux

Tags: linux, virtual-instruments

I have tried to search for a virtual pad on Google but failed at it.

So I was wondering if anyone in the stackexchange's sound community knows a linux software able to map a sound (.wav) to a key from the keyboard ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only actively maintained and full-featured Linux sampler I'm aware of is aptly titled [LinuxSampler](http://www.linuxsampler.org/).

You won't get great results transposing a single audio sample (the formants shift and it can sound pretty cheesy). If what you're looking for is an actual pad synthesizer, [ZynAddSubFX](http://zynaddsubfx.sourceforge.net/) can produce some great, lush sounds with the PADsynth algorithm.